# Django - Model field keeps the same value!

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

When I assign a value to an variable of a Field object, why when I reload the ModelForm isn't reassigned to default?

File

```
class CustomFile(ImageFile, FieldFile):
    def save(self, name, content, save = True):
        if self.field.override_name:
            self(CustomFile, self).save(self.field.override_name, content, save = save)
        else:
            self(CustomFile, self).save(generate_name(self.instance, name), content, save = save)
```

Field

```
class CustomImageField(ImageField):
    attr_class = CustomFile
    def __init__(self, overrided_name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.overrided_name = overrided_name
        super(CustomImageField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Model

```
class Test(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    file = CustomImageField()
```

AdminForm

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.old_instance = self.instance
```

Admin

```
class TestAdmin(Test):
    form = TestForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if form.old_instance:
            form.old_instance.file.delete(save = True)
            form.old_instance.file.field.override_name = form.old_instance.name
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin)
```

My problem is that every image I will upload will have the same name, until I restart the server!..
Why the object doesn't change?! In particular the Field object... when I trace it will result the same object .

I've solved it like so:

```
class CustomFile(ImageFile, FieldFile):
    def save(self, name, content, save = True):
        if self.field.override_name:
            self(CustomFile, self).save(self.field.override_name, content, save = save)
            self.field.override_name = None
        else:
            self(CustomFile, self).save(generate_name(self.instance, name), content, save = save)
```

I'm using Django 1.2.6, Python 2.6 and Windows!

Comment: Wait, why are you creating a custom field type? Couldn't you just use Django's built in ImageField type?

Comment: unfortunately no ... I must save the image, thumbs and original (for dynamic generated thumbs, watermarks etc) ... this part works ... My problem is why the django-admin form reuses the same field object?!.. Or better yet, what I've messed up?!..

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing, but isnt this part of code wrong?

```
form = TestForm
```

Should not it be creating an instance instead of referencing to class?

```
form = TestForm()
```

or same thing here?

```
attr_class = CustomFile  - > attr_class = CustomFile()
```

Comment: Umm ... no!.. Django uses the reference class to call it later on ... That way you can write your own CustomFields/CustomFiles. Check out the FileDescriptor class here: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/files.py. Anyway i believe i've found why this is happening: Django uses only one FileField instance and multiple FieldFile instances. It kinda acts like a wrapper ... I've solved it, i think, but i didnt have the time to write an coherent answer!